# AWS Ubuntu instance keeps dropping ssh connections

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

My AWS LightSail Ubuntu instances used to allow my ssh clients to stay connected forever. However, a newly created Ubuntu 20.04 instance now keeps dropping the ssh connection, even though connections on the same PC to other cloud Ubuntu instances remain uninterrupted. I am unable to tell whether it is due to inactivity.

I check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and the following are all unset:

```
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

What could be causing the connection to drop?

Comment: I can't help with why, but I can tell you my EC2 Ubuntu instance have never disconnected my ssh session.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your SSH logs should tell you why a connection was closed. On Ubuntu, you can find the logs under `/var/log/auth.log`.

Example:

`Aug  2 09:40:40 ubuntu sshd[25405]: Received disconnect from 172.16.0.5 port 54936:11: Connection terminated by the client.`

Based on the listed reason you can make the necessary modifications.